# Jekyll Block Tag with custom context

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Give an array in Jekyll’s _data structure:

In `_data/array.yml`:

```
- id: id1
  name: name1
- id: id2
  name: name2
```

How can I create a block tag that will lookup the object with the specified id and pass in a context inside the block tag? Like this

```
{% item id1 %}
  <p>{{ site.data.array.length }}</p>
  <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
{% enditem %}
```

I’ve made this so far:

```
module Jekyll
  class ItemBlock < Liquid::Block
    def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
      super
      @tag = markup
    end

    def render(context)

      jekyllSite = context.registers[:site]

      items = jekyllSite.data['array'].select { |item|
        item['id'] == context[@tag.strip]
      }

      context.environments.first['item'] = items.first

      super
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag("item", Jekyll::ItemBlock)
```

But now the `item` is available to the whole template even outside the block.

```
{% item id1 %}
  <p>{{ site.data.array.length }}</p>
  <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
{% enditem %}

<p>{{ item.name }}</p>
```

Is this the correct approach? Is there another way to achieve the above?